# Paperclip dimension validation error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

I want in my app user to be able to upload files with

> **at least** `width:800px` and `height: 550px`

I created in **app/models/dimensions_validator.rb** file
and the code

```
class DimensionsValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(value.queued_for_write[:original].path)
    width = options[:width]
    height = options[:height] 

    record.errors[attribute] << "Width must be at least #{width}px" if dimensions.width < width
    record.errors[attribute] << "Height must be at least #{height}px" if dimensions.height < height
  end
end
```

and in my **app/models/gig.rb** model

```
validates :image, :dimensions => { :width => 800, :height => 550 }
```

> **Question:** When i click on the submit button,without actually selecting any picture,it throughs an error saying `undefined method
>   "path" for nil:NilClass`
>    and it marks in red color the line 4 which is `dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(value.queued_for_write[:original].path)`

Maybe i need a code,to check if the image is present,something like `if image.present?` but where would i include that? i already use in the **gig model**  `validates_attachment_presence :image`

This is the error 
[image: error]

And this is my GigsController#update

```
def update
    if @gig.update(gig_params)
      redirect_to @gig, notice: "Gig was successfully updated"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm sorry what you mean in the first one,where? can you please write it as an answer.Thank you.

Comment: Can you check that your controller permitted params includes `image`? You can also look in the log output for something like `Unpermitted parameter: image`.

Comment: yes it is permitted.And in logs i get 
NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):                                                                                                                                                             
  app/models/dimensions_validator.rb:3:in `validate_each'                                                                                                                                                             
  app/controllers/gigs_controller.rb:71:in `update'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
validates :image, :unless => "image.queued_for_write[:original].blank?", dimensions: { width: 800, height: 550 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add other conditions to your validation. So, you might try adding `allow_blank` or an `if` condition:

```
validates :image, dimensions: { width: 800, height: 550 }, allow_blank: true
```

or maybe:

```
validates :image, dimensions: { width: 800, height: 550 }, if: Proc.new {|gig| gig.image? }
```

Comment: It doesn't work,it gives absolutely the same error,but with my current setting it works when i create a new gig,but not when i update it.See my edited question,the last picture.

Comment: I attempted to recreate your situation locally. By placing a `byebug` statement at the beginning of the custom validator, I was able to verify that the validator is *not executed* with either of the above approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use this `gem` for validation of image width and height with `Paperclip`: https://github.com/evedovelli/image_validators

Add it to your bundle:

```
gem 'image_validators'
```

And add the validation rules to your Model:

```
validates :image, dimensions: { greater_than_or_equal_to: { width: 800, height: 550 } }
```